# The 7 version tag is no longer permitted?

Tags: bug, status-completed

I've noted myself and other users have also seemed to note that stories can no longer be tagged with the "7" tag. Did I miss a memo somewhere?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287883/are-tags-with-a-name-made-of-just-numbers-still-allowed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried editing a question with that tag, and I got an error about that tag not being allowed. I will check what happened, but it seems the software running Stack Exchange doesn't allow that tag in the questions. I have a vague idea of why this happens; I just need to verify it.

As per [Are tags with a name made of just numbers still allowed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287883/are-tags-with-a-name-made-of-just-numbers-still-allowed) this has been now fixed. If they change the code, and introduce back this behavior, they will also make a post on the main meta site to explain why they introduced back this limitation.

Comment: T'was working as recently as 3 hours ago: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/222383/how-to-create-a-rule-to-combine-the-terms-of-2-fields-to-create-a-new-term-store

Comment: Yes, I noticed. I asked a question on the main site to understand if they don't want us to use number-only tags (since not even [tag:66] is allowed), or it is just a bug they need to fix. [tag:7] is not black-listed, so it's not an issue only on DA.

Comment: Indeed, and 8 still works fine it seems

Comment: Actually no it doesn't, so yeah this is definitely related to numeric tag names

Comment: Okay, great. If thats the case I'll mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry about this; this was my bad. It was impacting an API. I verified that we didn't have pure numeric tags on *some number* of sites, but I obviously failed and didn't thoroughly check all of them, which is my error. I will find another approach for the problem that I was trying to fix. The code has already been reverted. Again, sorry.

Comment: Not to hijack your answer, but does this mean you "test in production", or rather that you "don't have a representative test environment"??? Btw, are there any such site as X.stackexchange.com, whereas X = unittest, integrationtest, volumetest, useracceptancetest, etc?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens no, it simply means that we can't anticipate and test for every single scenario. We do indeed have a representative test environment, but I'm not telling you the url :)